# Mongoose Insert never returns in unit test

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, passport.js, kraken.js

I'm creating a unit test to test Passport, and the first step is to create a user.  Creating the user times out and the test is unable to progress.

Test (login.js):

```
'use strict';
var app = require('../index'),
    kraken = require('kraken-js'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    User = mongoose.model('User'),
    should = require('chai').should(),
    Q = require('q'),
    agent = require('supertest'),
    cookie,
    pUser = {
        firstName: 'pasport-test',
        lastName: 'user',
        userName: 'passport-user',
        email: 'passport-user@here.com',
        password: 'h@rdP@ssw0rd'
    }

    describe('#create user and log them in with passport', function () {
        this.timeout(10000);
        var mock;
        beforeEach(function (done) {
            kraken.create(app).listen(function (err, server) {
                mock = server;
                done(err);
            });
        });


        afterEach(function (done) {
            mock.close(done);
        });

        describe('#login the user', function () {
            it('should create a user', function (done) {
                var user = new User({
                    firstName: pUser.firstName,
                    lastName: pUser.lastName,
                    userName: pUser.userName,
                    email: pUser.email,
                    password: pUser.password
                });
                user.save(function(err, data) {
                    if(err) {
                        done(err);
                    } else {
                        done();
                    }
                });
                //it should then login that user with passport
            });
        });
```

If I connect o to mongoose directly:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/testing");
```

and require User this way:

```
User = require('../models/user');
```

It works.

I'd like to use the server and connection that the `beforeEach` sets up with kraken, so that inserts happen in the configured database...

Question is why does the mongoose insert never come back in the test?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean... I'm assuming the callback passed to `user.save` is not being called, so the test times out. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `mongoose.connect` in your test code. mongoose queues all pending operations until a first db connection is made, which is why your `save` callback never gets called.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Peter Lyons, I needed to perform the connect to the database.

I wrote a small helper to do this (that I can use across my test files).

db.js:

```
'use strict';
var nconf = require('nconf'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'testing';

//get the db config stuff for mongoose from the application config file
nconf.use('file', {
    file: process.cwd() + '/config/app.json',
    format: nconf.formats.json
});
var dbConf = nconf.get('databaseConfig')[env];



var db = function() {
    return {
        connect: function() {
            if(!mongoose.connection.db) {
                mongoose.connect("mongodb://" + dbConf.host + '/' + dbConf.database);
            }
        }
    };
};

module.exports = db();
```

Then in my tests:

```
var db = require('./db');

db.connect();
```

And the model classes perform as expected.